# Rails find_or_create_by more than one attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, many-to-many, dynamic-attributes

There is a handy dynamic attribute in active-record called find_or_create_by:

`Model.find_or_create_by_<attribute>(:<attribute> => "")`

But what if I need to find_or_create by more than one attribute?

Say I have a model to handle a M:M relationship between Group and Member called GroupMember. I could have many instances where member_id = 4, but I don't ever want more than once instance where member_id = 4 and group_id = 7. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to do something like this:

```
GroupMember.find_or_create(:member_id => 4, :group_id => 7)
```

I realize there may be better ways to handle this, but I like the convenience of the idea of find_or_create.

Answer (score 480, accepted):

Multiple attributes can be connected with an `and`:

```
GroupMember.find_or_create_by_member_id_and_group_id(4, 7)
```

(use `find_or_initialize_by` if you don't want to save the record right away)

**Edit:** The above method is deprecated in Rails 4. The new way to do it will be:

```
GroupMember.where(:member_id => 4, :group_id => 7).first_or_create
```

and

```
GroupMember.where(:member_id => 4, :group_id => 7).first_or_initialize
```

**Edit 2:** Not all of these were factored out of rails just the attribute specific ones.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/guides/source/active_record_querying.md

Example

```
GroupMember.find_or_create_by_member_id_and_group_id(4, 7)
```

became

```
GroupMember.find_or_create_by(member_id: 4, group_id: 7)
```

Comment: You might also like https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert - the first argument is a hash of attributes that is used to find or create a record

Comment: It is helpful to note that initialize calls the create() instead of new() that might be called in case of first_or_create

Comment: Can some one share a gist example of this usage?  I'm not familiar with its placement and calling.

Comment: I reverted the removal of Rails 3 code, since lots of people are not using Rails 4 yet.

Comment: Just to add: find_or_create_by_*() functions have been deprecated in Rails 4, however find_or_create_by() is NOT.
It is okay to use find_or_create_by(). Check the commit where this was added https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/eb72e62c3042c0df989d951b1d12291395ebdb8e and the official Rails 4.2 documentation for the usage: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.0/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by

Comment: Does the `find_or_create_by` is really deprecated in Rails 4? 
I just found a resource http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by under version of Rails 4.2.1

Answer (score 36):

In Rails 4 you could do:

```
GroupMember.find_or_create_by(member_id: 4, group_id: 7)
```

And use `where` is different:

```
GroupMember.where(member_id: 4, group_id: 7).first_or_create
```

This will call `create` on `GroupMember.where(member_id: 4, group_id: 7)`:

```
GroupMember.where(member_id: 4, group_id: 7).create
```

On the contrary, the `find_or_create_by(member_id: 4, group_id: 7)` will call `create` on `GroupMember`:

```
GroupMember.create(member_id: 4, group_id: 7)
```

Please see this relevant [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/eb72e62c3042c0df989d951b1d12291395ebdb8e) on rails/rails.

Answer (score 35):

For anyone else who stumbles across this thread but needs to find or create an object with attributes that might change depending on the circumstances, add the following method to your model:

```
# Return the first object which matches the attributes hash
# - or -
# Create new object with the given attributes
#
def self.find_or_create(attributes)
  Model.where(attributes).first || Model.create(attributes)
end
```

**Optimization tip:** regardless of which solution you choose, consider adding indexes for the attributes you are querying most frequently.

Comment: One thing to note is that this won't handle attributes that cannot be mass-assigned, while `find_or_create_by` will.

Comment: Marco, try `Model.where(attributes).instance_eval{|q| q.first || q.create}`.

Comment: ```find_or_create``` also has the benefit of using a transaction, where ```where….first || create``` introduces a race condition

Comment: I would say   `def self.find_or_create(attributes)
    self.where(attributes).first || self.create(attributes)
  end` so that you don't need to repeat `Model`

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger You don't need `self` inside the method body either (since you're looking to remove words!).

Comment: @mm - Using a transaction here does not prevent a race condition, unless you have configured a higher-than-normal (and less performant) isolation level on your RDBMS. Note that http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by specifically mentions that find_or_create_by is vulnerable to a race condition.

Answer (score 19):

By passing a block to `find_or_create`, you can pass additional parameters that will be added to the object if it is created new. This is useful if you are validating the presence of a field that you aren't searching by.

Assuming:

```
class GroupMember < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name
end
```

then

```
GroupMember.where(:member_id => 4, :group_id => 7).first_or_create { |gm| gm.name = "John Doe" }
```

will create a new GroupMember with the name "John Doe" if it doesn't find one with `member_id 4` `and group_id 7`

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
User.find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Penélope', last_name: 'Lopez')
User.where(first_name: 'Penélope', last_name: 'Lopez').first_or_create
```

Or to just initialize:

```
User.find_or_initialize_by(first_name: 'Penélope', last_name: 'Lopez')
User.where(first_name: 'Penélope', last_name: 'Lopez').first_or_initialize
```

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by