# create if doesn't exist function in ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Rails 3.2.8.  I need to create a status record if a status record doesn't already exist. If a status record exists, I don't do anything. So my code is something like this:

```
user_level_status = UserLevelStatus.where(user_id: user_id, level_id: level_id).first
if !user_level_status
  UserLevelStatus.create(user_id: user_id, level_id: level_id, status: UserLevelStatus::READY)
end
```

Is there a better way to handle this in Rails/ActiveRecord? Is there an equivalent mechanism as `find_or_create_by_`? Can I use `find_or_create_by_user_id` and also check for `level_id`? I would just be discarding the results so even that's not so elegant.

Answer (score 20):

Yes there is.

### Rails 3

```
user_level_status = UserLevelStatus.find_or_create_by_user_id_and_level_id(user_id, level_id)
```

### Rails 4:

```
user_level_status = UserLevelStatus.find_or_create_by(user_id: user_id, level_id: level_id)
```

And you should set the [default `status` in your model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550688/how-do-i-create-a-default-value-for-attributes-in-rails-activerecords-model).

Comment: This is the most elegant solution presented, but I want to be able to create the status record with 1 of many different statuses.  Sometimes it needs to be a READY status and sometimes it needs to be some other status.  I guess I could check the user_level_status object's status field and if nil, then set it.  Is there a way to set the status field within the find_or_create_by_* method?

Comment: as of Rails 4, the dynamically created versions of find_or_create_by_XXX seem to have been deprecated in favor of find_or_create_by(), passing in the name and value.

Answer (score 5):

You should use

```
UserLevelStatus.where(user_id: user_id, level_id: level_id).first_or_create(status: UserLevelStatus::READY)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`find_or_create_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4200277/297087)

```
hash = {user_id: user_id, level_id: level_id, status: UserLevelStatus::READY}
UserLevelStatus.find_or_create_by_user_id_and_level_id_and_status(hash)
```

EDITED For your case you should use following

```
hash = {user_id: user_id, level_id: level_id}
UserLevelStatus.find(:first, :conditions => hash) || UserLevelStatus.create(hash.merge({status: UserLevelStatus::READY})
```

Comment: This would create a new `UserLevelStatus` if the `status` field is different for the actual `user_id` and `level_id`, wouldn't it?

Comment: So if there is a validation for the uniqueness on `level_id` with scope of `user_id`, then your solution would create an invalid object.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is

```
UserLevelStatus.where(user_id: user_id, level_id: level_id).first ||
  UserLevelStatus.create(user_id: user_id, level_id: level_id, status: UserLevelStatus::READY)
```