# Correct way to create or update with multiple belongs_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, idioms

New to Rails and Ruby and trying to do things *correctly*.

Here are my models. Everything works fine, but I want to do things the "right" way so to speak.
I have an import process that takes a CSV and tries to either create a new record or update an existing one.

So the process is 1.) parse csv row 2.) find or create record 3.) save record

I have this working perfectly, but the code seems like it could be improved. If ParcelType wasn't involved it would be fine, since I'm creating/retrieving a parcel FROM the Manufacturer, that foreign key is pre-populated for me. But the ParcelType isn't. Anyway to have both Type and Manufacturer pre-populated since I'm using them both in the search?

CSV row can have multiple manufacturers per row (results in 2 almost identical rows, just with diff mfr_id) so that's what the .each is about

```
manufacturer_id.split(";").each do |mfr_string|
  mfr = Manufacturer.find_by_name(mfr_string)

  # If it's a mfr we don't care about, don't put it in the db
  next if mfr.nil?

  # Unique parcel is defined by it's manufacturer, it's type, it's model number, and it's reference_number
  parcel = mfr.parcels.of_type('FR').find_or_initialize_by_model_number_and_reference_number(attributes[:model_number], attributes[:reference_number])
  parcel.assign_attributes(attributes)

  # this line in particular is a bummer. if it finds a parcel and I'm updating, this line is superfulous, only necessary when it's a new parcel
  parcel.parcel_type = ParcelType.find_by_code('FR')

  parcel.save!
end


class Parcel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parcel_type
  belongs_to :manufacturer

  def self.of_type(type)
    joins(:parcel_type).where(:parcel_types => {:code => type.upcase}).readonly(false) unless type.nil?
  end
end


class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parcels
end


class ParcelType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parcels
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the [new_record?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new_record%3F) method is what you're looking for.

> **new_record?() public**
>
> Returns true if this object hasn’t been saved yet — that is, a record
>   for the object doesn’t exist yet; otherwise, returns false.

The following will only execute if the parcel object is indeed a new record:

```
parcel.parcel_type = ParcelType.find_by_code('FR') if parcel.new_record?
```

Comment: I guess I could also just do 'if parcel.parcel_type.ni?' but more what I"m looking for is a way to have a fresh Parcel have it's Manufacturer and Type already pre-populated (I can get the Mfr by creating the parcel via the Mfr)

Comment: Hmm, that might be a little unnecessarily complex if it's only really saving you one line of code without any performance gains. To be honest I'm not sure if you can even build a child object with more than a single parent pre-populated automagically by default. Your best bet might be one of the [ActiveRecord callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) methods if you truly want to leave everything up to ActiveRecord.

Comment: Gave you the answer as you are right, it's needlessly complex. The only place I really needed to do it was in a back-end import script so no biggie.

Answer (score 0):

What about 'find_or_create'?
I have wanted to use this from a long time, check these links.

- Usage:
  http://rubyquicktips.com/post/344181578/find-or-create-an-object-in-one-command
- Several attributes:
  [Rails find_or_create by more than one attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046607/rails-find-or-create-by-more-than-one-attribute)
- Extra:
  [How can I pass multiple attributes to find_or_create_by in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997034/how-can-i-pass-multiple-attributes-to-find-or-create-by-in-rails-3)