# Rails 4 find or create by method doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have a one to many association between jobs and companies and it works fine. In the job form view I have text_field for the company name with an autocomplete feature. The autocomplete works fine but the find_or_create_by don't create a new company if I put a company name that doesn't exist in the autocomplete list.

```
  def company_name
    company.try(:name)
  end

  def company_name=(name)
    @company = Company.find_or_create_by(name: name)
  end
```

Comment: If i create a job and put a new company that did not exit in the companies list the new company will not be created

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046645/1167094).

What used to be

```
@company = Company.find_or_create_by_name(name)
```

in Rails 4 is now

```
@company = Company.find_or_create_by(name: name)
```

Another way to do this in Rails 4 would be:

```
@company = Company.where(name: name).first_or_create
```

Answer (score 26):

```
Company.find_or_create_by(name: name)
```

It should work out of the box. Only thing that can prevent it from creating record is validation errors.

Try this in `rails console` to check if its working or not. 
And check the validation errors as well.

```
name = "YOUR TEXT FOR NAME ATTRIBUTE"
c = Company.find_or_create_by(name: name)
puts c.errors.full_messages
```

Comment: This is also a vlid answer

Comment: This is a good answer. I had validation errors after find_or_create_by that I missed and was wondering about. I added save! and found the validation errors. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This method is deprecated in rails 4.

Rails4 release message:

> Deprecated the old-style hash based finder API. This means that methods which previously accepted "finder options" no longer do.

It is deprecated method, but it should work. Maybe, Rails is not supporting it now.

You can get more info [click here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html) and check `11.2 Deprecations`.

Comment: Its the `find_or_create_by_name( name )` style that is deprecated. `find_or_create_by( name: name )` is still fine and the recommended way of doing it, as per the documentation you link to...