# ROR many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, many-to-many

I am new to ROR and i am trying to add a many to many association between emp and qualification.

https://github.com/clementprem/ROR---Basics

please check the above repo and can you please help me to add relationship data in the association table through check boxes.

Comment: Nobody is going to go through you entire app to find out where you are having problems. Please tell us exactly what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered. If you have not tried yet, then go back, try it yourself, and then come back with more specific questions. It might also be good to read the site FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am having problems in passing the check box values to the association table.

Comment: What kind of problem? Is there an error message?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am having problems in passing the check box values to the association table. I can print the values of qualification in the form but cant add the values to the emps_qualifications(association) table. I thought it is an automatic process when we add habtm tag in the models

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code where you are trying to create the associations. Also, see Naveed's suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails find\_or\_create by more than one attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046607/rails-find-or-create-by-more-than-one-attribute)

Answer (score 2):

for many to many association you need an intermediate join table may be you have missed it? .Have a look at

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: i have got the schema under migration and it also exist in the db (table name is :emps_qualifications)
my problem is the values are not added to the associate table