# Rails 3 find_or_create by more than one attribute mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

In this link [Rails find_or_create by more than one attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046607/rails-find-or-create-by-more-than-one-attribute) can use more that one attribute with active record.

How can I use more than attribute in mongoid?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the source in lib/mongoid/finders.rb:

```
# Find the first +Document+ given the conditions, or creates a
# with the conditions that were supplied.
    ...
# @param [ Hash ] attrs The attributes to check.
#
# @return [ Document ] A matching or newly created document.
def find_or_create_by(attrs = {}, &block)
    find_or(:create, attrs, &block)
end
```

you can see that find_or_create_by accepts a `{}` as the first argument. You can just pass in several conditions at once

```
something.find_or_create_by(name: 'john', age: 20)
```

and it should work.

Comment: How do I find by the first attribute only, and then - only in case that nothing is found - create with the other attributes?

Comment: @ChristofferJoergensen, Client.create_with(locked: false).find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Andy')   , take a look at the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1):

From the mongoid docs on [querying](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html):

> `Model.find_or_create_by`
>
> Find a document by the provided attributes, and if not found create
>   and return a newly persisted one.

Answer (score 0):

Christoffer,

I ran into a similar issue just recently and eventually figured it out after reading the source in the mongoid git repository:

In mongoid 3.1.0 stable branch, this works

```
    @new_object = NewObject.find_or_create_by(indexed_attribute: my_unique_value,
                                                        :attributeA => value,
                                                        :attributeB => value)
```