# Ruby Conditional If Else Assignment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

So I have the following code that I wanted to make a little more readable:

```
user = User.find_by_username(username)
user = User.new(credentials) if user.nil?
```

Essentially the first line is the default, the following line instantiates itself if it's not already set.

Is there a way I can clean this up a bit and get it onto a single line of code? Something like this maybe:

```
user = User.find_by_username(username) || User.new(credentials)
```

---

**Edit**

I now realize the the code I provided does exactly what I need, sorry for wasting cyberspace but feel free to suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: What's wrong with exactly the line you suggest?

Comment: Oh, what do you know that pseudo code actually worked

Comment: That really is a demonstration of the expressivity of the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, what you wrote is exactly the correct answer.

You could also write it this way, if preferred:

```
user = User.find_by_username(username)
user ||= User.new(credentials)
```

Keep in mind that your first example will only assign the second value if the first one is `nil`, but your second example and my example above will assign the second value on both `nil` and `false`.

*EDIT*: As mentioned by others, if you're working with Active Record you could also use a [dynamic attribute-based finder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Dynamic+attribute-based+finders)

```
user.find_or_initialize_by_username(credentials)
```

Answer (score 3):

its easier to do

```
user.find_or_create_by_name(credentials)
```

and credentials will have username there

see [Rails find_or_create by more than one attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046607/rails-find-or-create-by-more-than-one-attribute)

and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: Good thinking, but in this case I'm not looking to commit the object right off the hop.

Comment: Then you could use user.find_or_initialize_by_username(credentials)... see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Dynamic+attribute-based+finders