# Checking if the email had been already taken in the following if statement (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, omniauth

I have the following action:

**users.rb:**

```
  def omniauth_create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    unless user.email.blank?
      if user.id.nil?
        # Save the user since he hasn't been created yet
        user.save!
      end
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      # Send user to a form to fill his email
      #session[:omniauth] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except('extra')
      redirect_to(enter_email_path(oprovider: user.provider,
                                   ouid: user.uid,
                                   oname: user.name,
                                   opassword: user.password,
                                   opassword_confirmation: user.password))
    end
  end
```

It does the following:

- If the user's `email` is not blank, sign him in, and redirect him to his profile (and save him if his `id` is `nil`. In other words, if he hasn't been created yet).
- If the user's `email` is blank, send him to `enter_email_path` (where the user can enter his email).

Now I want to add another if statement that flashes an error if the `email` had been already taken, and redirects the user to the `root_path`

I'm not very sure how to do this, Any suggestions? (and where to put that if statement?)

**EDIT:**

Strange, got this instead of the redirect to the root path:

```
Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

I don't know if this helps but here is the origin of `from_omniauth`:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  end

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    new do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
      user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
      user.password = user.password_confirmation = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n=6) 
    end
  end
```

The code as it is right now:

**user.rb**:

```
# if user.email.present?
  if user.id.nil?
    # User.find_by_email(user.email).present?
    if User.exists?(:email => user.email)
      redirect_to root_path
    end
    user.save!
  end
  sign_in user
  redirect_back_or user
else
```

(the rest didn't change).

It seems like the code is ignoring the `if User.exists?(:email => user.email)` part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails has a method to check if an object [`exists`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists?) based on parameters. You could do this:

```
if user.email.present?
  if user.id.nil?
    if User.exists?(:email => user.email)
      # return redirect email is already token
    end

    # save user
  end
  # sign_in user
else
  # redirect to get email
end
```

By the way, I am not familiar with Omniauth so I am not sure what is right but [`new_record?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new_record?) is usually used when checking if object is already saved or not. If you have an `id`, it usually is.
If you are confused you could create functions in your User model for better reading like

```
class User
  def new?
    id.nil?
  end

  def email_taken?
    self.class.exists?(:email => email)
  end
end

# back to controller
if user.email.present?
  if user.new?
    if user.email_taken?
      # return redirect email is already token
    end

    # save user
  end
  # sign_in user
else
  # redirect to get email
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I'm getting `Validation failed: Email has already been taken` (please see my **EDIT**).

Comment: @alexchenco I did not write `return` after `email_taken?` by random. You want to go out of the function, don't want to save this user. So you should use `return redirect_to root_path` here.

Comment: @redirect_back_or user Oh sorry, didn't see that. I forgot what `return` did in Ruby. Thanks! By the way, why return wasn't necessary in `redirect_back_or user`?

Comment: @alexchenco because that is the end of the function and no other code will be executed after this. You could add it if you want but that would not change anything. In ruby, the last statement executed of a function is returned automatically.

Comment: Oh, I see, I was looking the "end" as the end of `if`. Didn't consider the `else` as an "end". Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 def omniauth_create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.email.present?
      if user.id.nil?
        if User.find_by_email(user.email).present?
          # send error email already be taken
          # or login with that user that means define that user for sign in
        else
          # save user and login with that user
          user.save!  
        end
        sign_in user
        redirect_back_or user
      end 
    else
      # Send user to a form to fill his email
      # session[:omniauth] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except('extra')
      redirect_to(enter_email_path(oprovider: user.provider,
                                   ouid: user.uid,
                                   oname: user.name,
                                   opassword: user.password,
                                   opassword_confirmation: user.password))

    end
```

Update

you can also use [find_or_create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046607/rails-find-or-create-by-more-than-one-attribute) method

```
def self.find_or_create(attributes)
  Model.where(attributes).first || Model.create(attributes)
end
```

**Update 2**

In your Modal file

```
  class << self
    def create_with_omniauth(auth)
      create! do |user|
        user.provider = auth['provider']
        user.uid = auth['uid']
        if auth['info']
          user.uid = auth['uid'] || ""
          user.name = auth['info']['name'] || ""
          user.email = auth['info']['email'] || ""
          user.access_token = auth['credentials']['token'] || ""
          user.oauth_token_secret = auth['credentials']['secret'] || ""
          user.oauth_token = auth['credentials']['token'] || ""
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

In your controller

```
  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.where(:provider => auth['provider'],:uid => auth['uid']).first || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url 
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! But got this: `Validation failed: Email has already been taken (please see my EDIT).`

Comment: Thanks! But I'm confuse, did you mean to put it in my `create` action or `omniauth_create` action? EDIT: But if email and password are empty, then I will get an error?

Comment: Yeah, I got this: `Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, Password confirmation can't be blank:`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want a rails answer or a SQL answer, but you could use the following SQL to find your response:

```
select id from users where email = :email
```

If this returns 0 rows, the email does not exist, if it returns 1, it does exist. I guess you could also use

```
Users#find(:first, :conditions => 'email = #{email}')
```

but I haven't tested this.

Comment: Rails answer. I want to put that in the controller (but the if statements are confusing me).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Users.find(:first, :conditions => 'email = #{user.email}')`? Sorry, if I'm mistaken.