# Rails 3 How to find out find_or_create which action was triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I just came across something that I have to do

```
find_or_create
```

or

```
where(attributes).first_or_create
```

as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046607/rails-find-or-create-by-more-than-one-attribute) suggests.

But there's something I have been wondering

Is there an way to determine which action was triggered? (Because I want to display proper notice if it's created) BTW. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `__method__` if ruby is `1.9.3+`

```
if ['new','include'].include? __method__ then
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: It's you again Michael. Thanks for the answer, could you give me a bit more details on how to use it in the controller?

Comment: thanks michael, now it seems like shweta's way is shorter. But I will keep this one in mind

Answer (score 1):

```
if Model.find_by_attributes(attributes)
  flash[:notice] = "record found"
else
  Model.create(attributes)
  flash[:notice] = "record created"
end
```

Comment: thanks. I thought about using if else as well, but I'm kinda interested in finding out the action when use `find_or_create` or `first_or_create`

Answer (score 1):

My personal belief is not to use `find_or_create`, instead use find and create separately, that way I think its more cleaner and extendible.

As an example , if you want to do some more stuff after your record has been created. And I strongly believe in the concept of one method should do one thing :),

So I would write something like this

HTH

Comment: I tried to use `__method__` as Michael suggested, but I'm kinda new to ruby and couldn't find a solution. I guess I probably just gonna go with shweta's answer. You do have a point. Thanks